# Android - Firestore toObject() cannot deserialize an object with a nested Array of Strings

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

This is my `Class` data model in Firestore:
[image: Class data model in Firestore]

Here is the `Class` in my Kotlin model.

```
data class Class(
    var teacher: String = "",

    val capacity: Int = 0, 

    val location: String = "",

    var roster: List<String> = ArrayList() // this doesn't work and neither does String or HashMap<String, String>
)
```

I attempt to grab the data for the class as such using Coroutines:

```
val snapshot = database.collection("class").get().await()
val class = snapshot.toObject(Class::class.java)
```

However, it fails to map the `roster` to an ArrayList and gives me the following stacktrace:

> E/FirebaseServiceImpl: getClass: FAILURE java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.lang.String (found in field 'roster')
>
> --------- beginning of crash
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.packagename.myapp, PID: 8809
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.lang.String (found in field 'roster')

I've also tried making `roster` a String and a HashMap but when I do it says it detects an `ArrayList`.

How can I grab an array of strings nested within an object if I'm using `toObject()`?

Comment: Are you sure that `roster` is **not** in some documents an array and others a String?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, I only have a few objects in the `class` collection and in all of them `roster` is an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there was absolutely nothing wrong with the code, it seems. When I deleted the collection and re-uploaded my collection's seed data to Firebase it resolved my issues, and I changed nothing in the code. Unfortunately I can't say what caused it but if you're having a similar issue maybe re-importing your data will help as well?