# How to covert the $document.data details to useful format so that I could use it in listviews

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to convert $document.data details to useful format so that I could use it for further applications. This is data from firestore documents.

```
private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            mFireStore.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("lastName","H").whereEqualTo("firstName", "Uc").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener{ documents ->
                    for(document in documents){
                        Log.d("TAG","${document.id}=>${document.data}")
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${document.id} => ${document.data}",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener{exception ->
                    Log.w("TAG","Error getting documents:",exception)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }
```

This is my code. Now when I run the code get this in the logcat

OL0rD4UfgHSh2K8UoTMnX6Xea6P2=>{lastName=H, image=, firstName=Uc, B=L, gender=, organization=, profileCompleted=0, mobile=0, blood group=o+, id=OL0rD4UfgHSh2K8UoTMnX6Xea6P2, email=jojoy09@gmail.com}

Now I want to convert this result to a useful format so that I could use it later. I wpuld like to convert the data so that I could load it in listview. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The Model that you used to set this data will be used here. You can convert the `documents` to your `Model` class using the `.toObjects()` method on it. Just use:

```
val myObjs = documents.toObjects(Model::class.java)
```

EDIT

For displaying this as a `Log` in `Logcat` use:

```
Log.d("myObjs  ","""
    $myObjs 
""".trimIndent())
```

Do tell if this doesn't work for you :)

Comment: How to display the myObjs list as a toast or convert it to hashmap?

Comment: updating answer for displaying it as a log :)

Comment: No this did not work. Application crashed.

Comment: hmm can you also edit your question and add the code for the `Model` class that you used while setting the data to `Firestore` and also the Complete `Log` message on crash? Since it does require you to have a `no-argument constructor` and in the case its missing the app will still crash.

Answer (score 0):

In the following for-loop:

```
for(document in documents) { ... }
```

The "document" object is of type [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot). When you call [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) on such an object, the type of object that is returned is a Map<String, Object>.

In Kotlin, this object is represented by `Map<String, Any>`. In order to get the data, you can simply iterate over the Map and get the data accordingly, using the following lines of code:

```
val map = document.data
for ((key, value) in map) {
    Log.d("TAG", "$key = $value")
}
```

Or even simpler, using:

```
map.forEach { (key, value) -> Log.d("TAG", "$key = $value") }
```

However, if you only need, the value of a particular property, for example, the value of the email address, you can simply get it by using [DocumentSnapshot#getString(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getString(java.lang.String)) method:

```
val email = document.getString("email")
Log.d("TAG", email)
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
jojoy09@gmail.com
.................
```

As I see in your screenshot, almost all of the properties are of type String. However, you can find different flavors for each type of field, like [getLong(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getLong(java.lang.String)), [getDouble(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getDouble(java.lang.String)), [getDate(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getDate(java.lang.String)), [getTimestamp(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getTimestamp(java.lang.String)), and so on.

Furthermore, if you need to get the entire document, and you want to convert it into an object of a specific class, as also @mehulbisht mentioned in his answer, you should use [DocumentSnapshot#toObject(Class valueType)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)). So assuming that you have a data class that looks like this:

```
data class User(
    var email: String? = null,
    var firstName: String? = null,
    var lastName: String? = null,
    //Other necessary fields
)
```

To convert the "document" object into an object of the "User" class, please use the following line of code:

```
val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)
Log.d("TAG", user.email)
```

The result in the logcat will be the same as above.

If you want to display a list of "User" objects in a ListView, then please check my answer from the following post:

- [What miss, with connect Firestore and ListView for random results in sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223779/what-miss-with-connect-firestore-and-listview-for-random-results-in-sample/50228240)

It's really simple to convert the Java code into Kotlin.

Comment: Regarding your issue, here you can find some info regarding the [no-argument constrcutore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844341/could-not-deserialize-object-class-does-not-define-a-no-argument-constructor-if/66856453#66856453).